# Dialogflow match mode support for Portuguese

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am looking for a means to effectively support machine learning for  Portuguese in Dialogflow since  Match Mode is not supported (so there no  ML support for Portuguese in Dialogflow). For my project this essentially means Portuguese can't not be supported  given the complex and diverse  number of  intents we support. It looks like I may have to change platforms altogether.

Has anyone come up with an alternative scheme that works with Dialogflow,  or  does anyone know if Portuguese will be fully supported in the near term?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, unfortunately DialogFlow's Match Mode doesn't currently support all languages: https://dialogflow.com/docs/machine-learning#match_mode

You could roll your own Portuguese NLU, and have DialogFlow pipe the messages to your servers through webhook fulfillment, but at that point DialogFlow's not doing much work for you, apart from possibly the 3rd party platform integrations.